# 2d compass positioning/logic

Tags: lua, positioning

as the title, I'm having major issues figuring this out. I'm trying to create this as a HUD for a game using lua as addon language.

I have a specific width of a bar, and on top of this bar, I'm trying to draw basically another bar with letters on it, for the direction the player is facing. I have the 0-360 degrees angle the player is facing, but I have no idea where to start in making a compass bar that looks like this image(bottom one):
http://s32.postimg.org/62kcq52it/firefox_u_ZBy_E_90965_229_70.png

so when the player changes angles, the bar would move too. I've thought of making one bar with the letters on it and somehow pushing the bar further and drawing the letters on a specific position on the bar, and then pushing the bar x pixels according to the degrees angle, but I realised this wouldn't make the letters repeat themselves.

Does anyone have any suggestions where to start?

Comment: Check out [math.atan2](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-math.atan2) and [math.rad](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-math.rad)

Answer (score 1):

Let **L** be the width in pixels of your compass bar.
You should prepare a picture of your double-compass:

```
N - E - S - W - N - E - S - W - N
```

This picture should have **4*L** pixels width.

Now, if you know an angle **A** the player is facing:

```
A = 0   for N
A = 90  for E
A = 180 for S
A = 270 for W
```

you can calculate the coordinates of the part of the picture which should be displayed in the compass bar:

```
x_left < x < x_rigth
```

where:

```
x_left = math.floor((90 + (A + 180) % 360) * L / 180)
x_right = x_left + L
```